# Como faço para não repetir resultados do RAND() em php?

Tags: php, mysql

Preciso criar um simulado que irá fazer um SELECT de 5 questões de forma aleatória.

Estou usando o `ORDER BY RAND()`, porém os resultados se repetem, e não sei como posso arrumar isso.

Até cheguei a criar um vetor que armazenasse o código de cada questão, mas não sei como compará-lo na hora de fazer o `SELECT`.

Alguém sabe como posso arrumar esse problema?

O código:

```
$con = conectar();
$x=1;
for($i=$x; $i<=$x+4; $i++){
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM simulado where cod_disc like 1 order by RAND()";
 $res = mysqlexecuta($con,$sql);
 $row = mysql_fetch_array($res);
 echo $i . ") " . $row['enunciado'];                                 
 $questoes[$i] = $row ['cod_questao'];
}
```

*O método mysqlexecuta apenas executa a query e verifica se houve algum erro na execução.

Comment: O ORDER BY RAND por si só não repete nenhum dado. Basicamente é questão de tirar a query do loop, pois o problema é que você faz vários SELECTs e a cada SELECT você está refazendo o RAND desnecessariamente (e mudando a sequência, o que causa repetição). Com um SELECT só já vem vários registros sem repetir, basta ficar repetindo o mysql_fetch_array para pegar o próximo. Além disso, seu loop está um bocado complexo, pra que serve o $x? Aparenta algum tipo de paginação, mas se for isso, precisa [edit] e por o problema completo, pois também vai afetar a questão do RAND

Comment: Refaz a logica do loop for(). Execute essa consulta varias vezes direto no console do seu sgbd e veja que o rand() nunca vai se repetir.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O `ORDER BY RAND()` por si só não repete nenhum dado. Ele apenas varia a ordem da saída.

Aparentemente a solução para o seu caso é tirar a *query* do loop, pois o problema é que você faz vários `SELECT`s e a cada `SELECT` você está refazendo o `RAND` desnecessariamente (e a cada momento, muda a sequência, o que causa repetição).

Com um `SELECT` só já vem vários registros sem repetir, basta ficar repetindo o `mysql_fetch_array` para pegar o próximo.

Seria algo mais ou menos assim:

```
$con = conectar();
$x=1;
$sql = "SELECT * FROM simulado where cod_disc like 1 order by RAND()";
$res = mysqlexecuta($con,$sql);

for($i=$x; $i<=$x+4; $i++){
 $row = mysql_fetch_array($res);
 echo $i . ") " . $row['enunciado'];                                 
 $questoes[$i] = $row ['cod_questao'];
}
```

Notei que seu loop está um pouco complexo, pra que serve o `$x`? Aparenta algum tipo de paginação, se for isso precisa rever a estratégia para não repetir entre páginas. Melhor seria usar o `LIMIT` neste caso (e um valor no *seed* do `RAND`):

```
$con = conectar();
$seed = mt_rand(); // Bole um jeito de sortear no primeiro acesso, mas
                   // manter o valor nas páginas seguintes pra não repetir
$pagina = 1;
$itens = 4;
$i = ($pagina - 1) * $itens + 1;

$sql = "SELECT * FROM simulado where cod_disc like 1 order by RAND($seed) LIMIT $i, $itens";

$res = mysqlexecuta($con,$sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
    echo $i . ") " . $row['enunciado'];                                 
    $questoes[$i] = $row ['cod_questao'];
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: Que simples, estou até incrédula! Acho que eu não tinha entendido muito bem como funcionada esse mysql_fetch_array, mas agora entendi direitinho. Quanto ao $x, ele me ajuda na manipulação dos FOR. Como o simulado possui várias categorias, separei cada uma em um for diferente, e usei o $x para guardar a quantidade de questões após passar por cada categoria. Muito obrigada, funcionou certinho!